# Nil IBOutlet from embedded View Controller using Pulley library

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewcontroller

As per "How To Use" from https://github.com/52inc/Pulley
I have a PulleyViewController with 2 UIViewContainers, and each has a UIViewController embedded into those containers with an embed segue.

I'm now finding that all IBOutlets I create in that embedded ViewController are nil at runtime. In the storyboard and swift files they show as connected, and all compiles well. But at runtime if I do something like `tableview.delegate = self` inside `viewDidLoad()` I get an "unexpectedly unwrapped nil" crash. 
This happens for all IBOutlets I try to use.

If I don't programmatically use any of the outlets, the project *technically* runs (Pulley library works, table views drag, scroll view scrolls), but obviously I can't update/click any cells or actually *do* anything beyond looking pretty.

I've tried cleaning the project, deleting derived data, restarting xcode.

I am new to xcode, and was curious if this has to do with embedding ViewControllers into Containers? Before adding in the Pulley Library all was working well and I felt like I understood the process of app building. Now it seems I don't understand things as well as I thought.